# If I have a template class, can I determine if the templated object has an overload of operator<<(std::ostream&)?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to substitute something in the dots to ensure this function is complete? I'd like to use this in something I'm developing, but I'm not sure how I can determine if a thing is printable without knowing what kind of things I might get.

```
template<typename U>
RunSomething(T& a1)
{
if(...)
    {
       std::cout << a1 << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up "expression SFINAE".

Comment: >`but I'm not sure how I can determine if a thing is printable`

that's what your compiler is supposed to check

Comment: Not sure, [maybe it supports enough](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/06/07/expression-sfinae-improvements-in-vs-2015-update-3/).